# Get a key from a session array

Tags: php, arrays, session

I have an array that is stored in a session like so:

```
$_SESSION['shortlistArray'][2];
```

Outputs

```
Peter
```

But how do I do this the other way round and use 'Peter' to get the array key?

Comment: Can you have multiple Peters in that array, or just at most one?

Answer (score 2):

Use array_search. It will return the key of the matched item.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to `array_search()` if you have to find the keys of many values, use [`array_flip()`](http://php.net/manual/function.array-flip.php) to swap array keys and values:

```
$byvalue = array_flip($_SESSION['shortlistArray']);
echo $byvalue['Peter'];

// 2
```